# Android Streaming Video: Does anyone know why the direct path of youtube videos that keepvid.com finds only works locally?

Tags: android, url, header, youtube, video-streaming

I am trying to stream a youtube video within an android application I am developing. I understand I could just leave this to youtube's app or download the video and throw it in the res folder to play it locally, but after trying both of these methods I really feel this way is more appropriate for the app I'm developing.

Anyway I went ahead and used keepvid.com to find the actual direct path to the .3gp and .mp4 videos I wanted to stream and threw this path into my code. Worked great at first but then I noticed a bug/problem or error on my part. Apparently the path that I get from keepvid.com works only locally. In other words I ran the keepvid program on my laptop at school and the path I got worked just fine from my laptop as well as my android phone when I was at school. However, when I got home neither worked. I then ran keepvid on my home desktop and the path I got worked just fine on my desktop, but it was a different path than before and this new path didn't work on my laptop or phone. Furthermore, I then ran keepvid on my laptop at home and got yet another path which worked on my laptop and phone but not on my desktop. Finally, as I suspected, if I shut off the wifi on my phone and use the 3g then it doesn't work.

Here is the path I got on my laptop at home:

http://**o-o.preferred.comcast-dfw1**.v7.lscache5.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?el=watch&begin=0&yms=10nhw2pvnws&dnc=1&itag=36&**ip=174.0.0.0**&app=youtube_mobile&signature=7B5BEE0319B31A03EADE1425C72B5AE6DC2D9231.2AE56C12AD3002703AB0A4EBCFFB854E592F0348&sparams=begin%2Ccp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clen%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cexpire&len=461000&ratebypass=yes&source=youtube&expire=1333094625&sver=3&key=yt1&ipbits=8&cp=U0hSSFBUUl9HT0NOMl9ITlZHOjQ5bWd2MHV2cHV0&id=c396447feb377216&title=Eco%20Express%20Car%20Wash

Here is the path I got from my laptop at school:

http://**o-o.preferred.dfw06s08**.v7.lscache5.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?el=watch&begin=0&yms=XpNWtXMQbJc&dnc=1&itag=36&**ip=64.0.0.0**&app=youtube_mobile&signature=23AA61F3611F98331027789A3FA7E88AD61A60A2.8495B80090990C13B7C3577ECB156E16A0AFC66E&sparams=begin%2Ccp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clen%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cexpire&len=461000&ratebypass=yes&source=youtube&expire=1333069425&sver=3&key=yt1&ipbits=8&cp=U0hSSFBRV19HT0NOMl9IS0FFOlltTVZzVE9WYkhk&id=c396447feb377216&title=Eco%20Express%20Car%20Wash

Here is the path I am now getting from a desktop at school:

http://**o-o.preferred.dfw06s08**.v7.lscache5.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?el=watch&begin=0&yms=FHG3ms3Jd5A&dnc=1&itag=36&**ip=207.0.0.0**&app=youtube_mobile&signature=C2825B1084B9A480B4CB4E64EDD4ADC5A7536B65.8F12D3198D8345170E554C5B0629F19CF9267260&sparams=begin%2Ccp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clen%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cexpire&len=461000&ratebypass=yes&source=youtube&expire=1333065825&sver=3&key=yt1&ipbits=8&cp=U0hSSFBRU19HT0NOMl9IS1dJOkdFRjRsbzdLaDVC&id=c396447feb377216&title=Eco%20Express%20Car%20Wash

I am particularly lost in trying to understand why keepvid would format the url differently depending on my machine or ISP? This certainly won't work as a solution to my android application but can anyone shed some light on what is going on with this path I am getting or perhaps suggest another site that I can upload this video to be hosted for my app for free.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are a multitude of reasons, none of which are actually to do with KeepVid. I'm sure you've noticed already, but it's not just "formatting", it's actually a different (related) URL. I suspect that in the case of your laptop at home, you use Comcast as your internet provider. No doubt Google has a deal with Comcast to cache some of their popular content on Comcast's servers. This reduces the amount of traffic sent over the internet as a whole, and is probably good for both Comcast and Google. I also believe that the URL contains a sort of session which expires to discourage hotlinking.

Comment: Thanks Kabuko. Yes you appear to be right. I now see there are a bunch of reasons why this approach isn't working and they are not because of KeepVid. YouTube does appear to use some sort of session or method of checking who is requesting the video to ensure that people cannot simply find the URL of a video and use it to stream from YouTube's servers however one chooses. I guess I should have known that YouTube would go to great lengths to ensure people don't piggy back off them, or as you called it hotlinking.

Comment: Nonetheless I remain convinced that their system is not perfect and that this can be done. However, I will concede that it is far beyond my skill level and will try to let this idea go.. at least for now.. But I still think its an interesting subject and if anyone can contribute any more to this post it would be greatly appreciated.